# iPhone - Conforming to a protocol without importing header files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, import

Recently I downloaded the [open source project zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/), the project itself it not really relevant to my question, what I still can't figure out is how in his viewcontroller he is able to do this:

```
//
//  EmbedReaderViewController.h
//  EmbedReader
//
//  Created by spadix on 5/2/11.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EmbedReaderViewController
    : UIViewController
    < ZBarReaderViewDelegate >
{
    ZBarReaderView *readerView;
    UITextView *resultText;
    ZBarCameraSimulator *cameraSim;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ZBarReaderView *readerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *resultText;

@end
```

That is it, that is the whole file, how can he see the delegate and the ZBarReaderView and ZBarCameraSimulator, without importing anything???.

My implementation is working, but I of course have to import the files, and as I was looking at the example, it really caught my attention that he was not importing anything... how is that possible??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Projects usually have a `pch` file (pre-compiled/prefix header) in them; this file is automatically included in every other code file of the project. If the `pch` file contains an `#import` to the protocol file, then every file in the project will be aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

He must have either a forward declaration or the import in the prefix header file, which is a file in the project ending in `.pch`, that is automatically imported by all source files in the project.